# How to use default value in input fields if user enters negative value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form whose input fields are generated dynamically. user can fill my form input fields either manually or by using autocomplete function. to use autocomplete function, user have to select any one option from the dropdown box and thereafter input fields are filled automatically. by using the values in input fields, i perform a simple calculation to calculate a final value. this calculation is executed when a user clicks the button present in the bottom of input fields.

all the things were going good. but during testing my this code, i found that if a user enter negative amount or zero in Dynamically generated input fields, i get a wrong value or unexpected value. after spending some hours on it, i found that if i use default values for my input fields instead of entered values (which could be used when a user enters negative amount or zero in input field), the problem could be solved. but unfortunately, i am unable to solve this problem on my own.

can someone please help me to solve this problem. i will be very grateful to him.

here is my code.....

```js
// define the headings here, so we can access it globally
// in the app
let headings = []

// appending the created HTML string to the DOM
function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}

// the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
// to the DOM
function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Company') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
}

// receiving data
// this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
// so it's the best to return a Promise object
// that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const companyData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
        companyData.push({ ...company
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(companyData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Company'
    $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#company").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      // just so we see what data we are using
      // console.log(data)
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
      initInputs(headings)
    })

});

//calculation for Rating value
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Cal").click(function() {
    var peVal = 0,
      roceVal = 0,
      sgVal = 0,
      dyVal = 0;
    jQuery(".fields input").each(function() {
      var idHeading = $(this).attr("id");
      if (idHeading == "PE") {
        peVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "ROCE") {
        roceVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "SG") {
        sgVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "DY") {
        dyVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    });
    var output = peVal + roceVal + (2 - sgVal) - (4 - dyVal / 2);

    $("output[name='amount']").text(output);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
      <label for="company">Company: </label>
      <input id="company"><br /><br />

      <div class="fields"></div>
      <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
      <button type="button" id="Cal">Button</button>
      <p>
        <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
      </p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If value negative, display the defaultValue.

Comment: user is allowed to enter any value in input fields. i will have to do it from my side. thanks in advance msg

Comment: don't want and need to display. instead, if entered value in input field is negative or zero, then just have to use default value of that input field. thanks in advance kevin B

Comment: I think what they are saying is to not allow the user to submit `invalid` values. In turn you catch those via validation and direct the user to change it to a absolute number before submission.

Comment: if the user enters positive amount in input fields, then my calculation function in javascript works correctly. but if user enters negative value or zero in input field, the calculation function performs wrongly. therefore, if user enters negative amount or zero in input fields, then i need to use default values of that input fields for calculation. thanks in advance msg

Comment: Right. so add a conditional and do the thing you need. Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: user is allowed to submit any type of amount. i need to do this thing from my side. thanks in advance CQ Smooth

Comment: i tried to solve this on my own. but unfortunately, failed in this. i need someones help. thanks in advance Kevin B

Comment: You only seem to care about 4 fields in your calculations. And you already have used conditionals so, what have you tried and why didn't work? (Why can't you `val < 1 ? defaultValue : val` ?)

Comment: i need to work with all fields. but just for now, i am working with only 4 fields so that any work would not become lengthy. when i have final code, i will adjust it accordingly. also, i had got this code through my friend. and i really don't know how to solve this issue on my own. can you please provide me a working solution. thanks in advance msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use keyup event and check for negative and zero values and set to default input value

1. Use key up event and check entered value on every key input
2. For negative and zero value , update input value to default

Working code

```js
var defaultVal = $('input').val();
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  if($(this).val().indexOf("-") !== -1 || $(this).val() == 0){
    $(this).val($(this).attr('value'))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1">
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/orKPwN?editors=1010

Updated code with code snippet mentioned in question

```js
let headings = []
const defaults = {PE: 100, PB: 60, DE: 1, PS: 1};

// appending the created HTML string to the DOM
function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}

// the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
// to the DOM
function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Company') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
}

// receiving data
// this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
// so it's the best to return a Promise object
// that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const companyData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
        companyData.push({ ...company
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(companyData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Company'
    $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#company").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      // just so we see what data we are using
      // console.log(data)
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
      initInputs(headings)
    })

});

//calculation for Rating value
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  $("#Cal").click(function() {
    var peVal = 0,
      roceVal = 0,
      sgVal = 0,
      dyVal = 0;
    $(".fields input").each(function() {
      var idHeading = $(this).attr("id");
      if (idHeading == "PE") {
        peVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "ROCE") {
        roceVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "SG") {
        sgVal = parseInt($(this).val());
      }
      if (idHeading == "DY") {
        dyVal = parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    });
    var output = peVal + roceVal + (2 - sgVal) - (4 - dyVal / 2);

    $("output[name='amount']").text(output);
  });
});

  $('body').on('keyup', '.fields input', function(){
  if($(this).val().indexOf("-") !== -1 || $(this).val() == 0){
    $(this).val(defaults[$(this).attr('id')])
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
      <label for="company">Company: </label>
      <input id="company"><br /><br />

      <div class="fields"></div>
      <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
      <button type="button" id="Cal">Button</button>
      <p>
        <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
      </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qzeLje

Comment: you don't need to store the default value, it is always available from the value attribute or the defaultValue property.

Comment: if user enter valid number other than default, then $(this).val() will change to new value

Comment: Right, .val looks at the value property, not the value attribute or the defaultValue property. they are three different things. `.val()`, `.attr('value')`, `.prop('defaultValue')`. The latter two return the default value.

Comment: yes @KevinB, any option works , as there are multiple ways to get element's attribute value , updated my answer using attr

Comment: thanks for your answer Naga Sai A, but can you please adjust it according to my code and provide me a working solution. i am not so good in coding. i will be very grateful to you for this. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Naga Sai A, thanks for your help but i required something different. Please check this code "https://code.sololearn.com/WMY9o8QX2ZwL/". The working of DEFAULT VALUE Function in this code is as same as I need. The only issue is that i can't use it for dynamically generated input fields. Can you please solve this issue for me. I will be very grateful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user11651048, i dont default value for input fields ...please include default values also for the fields

Comment: @user11651048, updated codepen with keyup integration with code mentioned in question , test for PE,PB, DE,PS fields for default values... If I was able to help you, feel free to mark as accepted and upvote as it was downvoted

Comment: @Naga Sai A, i really appreciate your help and updated answer. But it is not what I need. I needed exactly as same as I have shared with you in the example code "code.sololearn.com/WMY9o8QX2ZwL". The only difference is that I am using dynamic input fields. In your provided code,  when a user enters negative value or zero in input fields,  it is automatically updated to default values.  But I don't want to show default values to the user. Instead,  if the user enters negative value or zero in input fields,  I want to use default values for executing calculation instead of entered values.

Comment: @user11651048, please add those details in question , i think it was updated in question to set default value "i found that if i set default values for my input fields (which could be used when a user enters negative amount or zero in input field)"

Comment: @Naga Sai A, I know you can do this. Eagerly waiting to mark your answer as accepted answer.  But I can do this only when I get my answer. Waiting for your updated answer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Naga Sai A, Sorry if I made any mistake. But now,  are you able to understand what I needed?....

Comment: Naga Sai A,  i need your help. Please help me.

Comment: @user11651048, updated code in code.sololearn , to use default incase of 0 and negative values - https://code.sololearn.com/WGJU6L23aYTy/#js

Comment: Naga Sai A, Sorry, If there is a mistake in understanding from my side. Brother I have mentioned the code of solo learn to only let you understand what kind of function i am referring. I need to work with the code i provided in the question. I am dealing with Dynamic input fields. In your previous updated answer,  the solution you provided was somewhere as same as I needed. But the only problem was that i don't want to show the default values to the user.

Comment: The working of the Code should be like this. " If the user enters zero or negative value in a input field say A, then the JavaScript function for Calculation should use default value of A".  But in your answer,  the code replaces input value with Default value, if user enters negative value or zero.  Hope you are now able to understand  brother what I really needed.

Comment: I know my question is taking little more time of yours. And for this, I am really grateful and appreciate for your help and efforts you made. But I also know that you can solve this problem! Brother,  please help me. Eargely waiting to mark your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qzeLje  , fixed it..check it once... currently fixed for PE as mentioned in question

Comment: Now that is what I wanted. Really helpful. But can you please tell me how can i fix it for other Input fields also.??  Thanks in advance

Comment: @user11651048, updated for all inputs .check it once - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qzeLje

Comment: Finally got the answer.. Thanks for your efforts Naga Sai A. But can you please check why it is not working here "https://code.sololearn.com/Woe3z0zK7fVg/". Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure about code.sololearn, copied same code to codepen and it works fine - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wVBNxr

Comment: No problem Naga Sai A,  thanks for your help and efforts. Now,  I am marking your answer as accepted answer. 

Comment: Naga Sai A, before .... I thought I have got my solution but I was wrong.  There is some error in your code. it is showing only 63 as a final value again and again. I changed values of input fields multiple times but the calculated final value remain same in all cases. Please check it.

Comment: @user11651048, updated codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wVBNxr, issue is with the isNaN, use !isNaN and assign value

Comment: @user11651048, is this duplicate ticket of above question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916957/how-to-set-default-values-in-dynamic-input-fields-if-user-enter-negative-values